# Parameter variable not substituted in ssh plugin in Jenkins

Tags: svn, ssh, jenkins

I am trying to do an svn checkout on a remote machine by using [SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin)

The parameter is not getting substituted when the script is run. But if I specify the values directly without parameters, the checkout seems to be happening.

```
09:07:31 cd /home/ddk/
09:07:31 pwd
09:07:31 svn co https://#####/project/branches/release/$VERSION/ .
09:07:31 VERSION=v200: Command not found
09:07:31 VERSION: Undefined variable
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameterized jobs don't necessarily have its parameters exposed as variables available for build steps. Try using the env inject plugin and configure the version parameter to be injected to the build.

I have done this for some jobs in my Jenkins instance.

Comment: How to use Env Inject plugin?

Comment: Install the env inject plugin from under manage plugin in your Jenkins. You can find the env inject plugin in your job configuration build step drop down. Make sure you select this build step before the ssh plugin. Configure as given in the env inject plugin wiki page.